# Как подставить дату в название файла?

Tags: bat

```
D:
cd D:\backup
pg_dump > backup.sql
```

Нужно чтобы в имени файла была дата, год-месяц-день

```
pg_dump > backup_2017_10_16.sql
```

Comment: Формат даты важен?

Comment: Конечно, формат даты важен. Для сортировки например

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set year=%date:~-4%
set month=%date:~3,2%
set day=%date:~0,2%
if "%month:~0,1%" == " " set month=0%month:~1,1%
if "%day:~0,1%" == " " set day=0%day:~1,1%

pg_dump > backup_%year%_%month%_%day%.sql
```